# Cannot read property of 'variable' undefined

Tags: p5.js

I'm a student making a game for a summative, and an error is popping up that I have no idea how to solve it. I'm a bit of a coding newbie so any help is appreciated!

I've tried changing the variables in the for statement, but still no luck.

```js
for (let i=0; i<4; i+=1){
    if (dotCollideColour[i]!=dotColour[i]){
        dotCollide = false;
        break;
      }
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined.

I'd just like to be able to get this error to go away while still having my game to work. I'm fine sharing my full code if it's needed to help.

Comment: I have them defined earlier on in my code though. That's why this error is confusing me. I have let dotCollideColour;
let dotColour = [248,203,29,255]
let dotCollide = true;

Comment: `dotCollideColour` has to be an array too e.g. `let dotCollideColour = [0, 0, 0, 0]`

Answer (score 0):

Edit the condition to `dotCollideColour && dotColour && dotCollideColour[i] != dotColour[i]` to make the error go away for now. But you still will have to correct the issue in a near future.

The issue being that `dotCollideColour` or/and `dotColour` is undefined.